# Recursive function: this expression should have type unit.

Tags: ocaml

This function:

```
let rec foo () =
    try
    let line = input_line stdin in
    (try
        Mparser.tex_expr lexer_token_safe (Lexing.from_string line);
        print_string ("SUCCESS\n")
        with
        Mtexutil.Illegal_tex_function s -> print_string ("$T" ^ s ^ " " ^ line ^ "\n")
          | LexerException s            -> print_string ("$L" ^ line ^ "\n")
          | Parsing.Parse_error         -> print_string ("$P" ^ line ^ "\n")
          | _                           -> print_string ("$S " ^ line ^ "\n"));
    flush stdout;
    foo ();
    with
    End_of_file -> ()
;;
```

gives the error:

```
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

for the line starting with `Mparser.tex`.

How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the compiler is warning you that `Mparser.tex_expr` returns a value that you're not using. You can get rid of the warning by making it clear that you're throwing the value away purposely. That's what the `ignore` function is for:

```
ignore (Mparser.tex_expr lexer_token_safe (Lexing.from_string line));
```

In some cases I think things read better with `let ... in` rather than a semicolon:

```
let _ = Mparser.tex_expr lexer_token_safe (Lexing.from_string line) in
...
```